# How to implement bootstrap date picker?

Tags: angular, datepicker, calendar, angular-ui-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I have date picker plugin in my packages, when I implement, I am able to see the calender. How can I see the calender .

This is what I have tried

```
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedToDate"
                    [bsConfig]="{
                      dateInputFormat: 'DD-MMM-YYYY',
                    }"
                    [minDate]="selectedFromDate"
                    [maxDate]="maxDate"
                    name="toDate"
                    bsDatepicker
                  />
```

I have gone through different forums and followed the same but didnt help, please assist me.

Comment: try change type to "date"

Comment: do you have any errors on your console ?